# Check Auth::user() from middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I try to check in middleware if user is authenticated by calling `Auth::user()`
But it returns null. I call this middleware last in list of `protected $middleware` section in `Kernel.php`. Is there an way to check from middleware if user is authenticated or how I should do it another way?

Addition: I'm using Zizaco Entrust. May be it is why it doesn't work
And I'm using Laravel 5.5

my app/HTTP/Kernel.php:

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\FirstLoginPasswordChange::class,
    ];
```

my FirstLoginPasswordChange middleware:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Entrust;

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd(Auth::user()); // returns null
// or
        dd(Auth::check()); // returns false
// or
        dd(\Entrust::user()); // returns null

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try using `$request->user()` or `auth()` helper function?

Comment: It should work take a look at my code is working perfectly fine: https://github.com/avored/ecommerce/blob/master/src/Http/Middleware/AdminAuth.php

Comment: try it : if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}

Comment: Purvesh, I don't see Kernel.php in your project in app/HTTP/ how you added your middleware there ?

Comment: Alihossein shahabi, Auth::check() returns false, even when I login in previous request

Comment: try this Auth::guard('user')->check()

Comment: I don't have guard named 'user', only 'web' one.

Comment: I'm using Zizaco Entrust. May be it is why it doesn't work

Comment: Make sure the `StartSessions` middleware is enabled before your middleware. If you haven't started sessions before calling `Auth::user()`, it will return null. https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.html

Comment: this works for me! Thanks
But why there were no such middleware by default in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem solved by moving middleware from `protected $middleware` section in Kernel.php to `protected $routeMiddleware` section in Kernel.php
using this article:
http://laraveldaily.com/password-expired-force-change-password-every-30-days/

Answer (score 1):

To check if user is authenticated you can do as Laravel Docs states:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; //be sure to add the facade

if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

If you are trying to get user details and do some logic, then you can do this in your middleware:

```
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{


    $role = Auth::user()->role; //Obtenemos el rol del usuario

    if ($role != "user"){
        return redirect('/logout');
    }

    return $next($request);

}

}
```

Comment: where i should to call this middleware ?

Comment: @IlyaKolesnikov right into your middleware... just remember to call `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` in the top of your middleware, then call the function where you need it in your middleware.

Or could you explain with more details and paste code from your middleware?

Comment: I'm using Zizaco Entrust. May be it is why it doesn't work